# Calling a function within a function with python

Tags: python, function

so here is my problem, I am trying to create a function in Python that refers to another function
Here is my code:

```
def movies_creation():
    for director in directors:
        for i in range((int(director.age)-20)/random.randint(1,5)):
            movie = MOVIE([], random.randint(1960, 2015), 
            random.choice(movie_genre), 0, [], director, 0, 0, 0)

            movie_title_type = random.randint(1,40)

            if movie_title_type == 1:
                title_colors()
    director.filmography.append(movie)

def title_colors():
    movie.name.append(random.choice(title_colors))
```

Now when I try to run this code I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\TS\gui.py", line 7, in 
    movies_creation()   
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\TS\Movies.py", line 401, in movies_creation
    title_colors()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures\Python\TS\Movies.py", line 343, in title_colors
    movie.name.append(random.choice(title_colors)) NameError: global name 'movie' is not defined
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Please read the error message: `NameError: global name 'movie' is not defined`. You probably want to pass `movie` as a parameter.

Comment: The variable `movie` is not shared between functions. You should manually pass it to `title_colors`. You should read the documentation about "scopes" in Python.

Comment: What is unclear in message you've received?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is that you should pass the `movie` variable to the method `title_colors`:

```
title_colors(movie)

def title_colors(m):
    m.name.append(random.choice(title_colors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, my problem was my function had the same name than a list in my program. changed the name and everything works fine now